# Connecting hivemetastore through datanode

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

Currently i am using namednode, mysql for metastore and hive CLI on one single node. And another nodes as datanode. mysql is running on master (namenode). It works fine when i try to get metadata(show tables) hive(on master). Now i was trying to get the same metadata on datanode. But couldn't successed. I also tried starting thrift service on master and then tried to connect still didn't successed.

Comment: Can you post any log information that you get when you run a command on the CLI?

Comment: @climbage Here is the Error on hive CLI which i am getting.    FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Comment: Run this in the Hive CLI `set hive.metastore.uris;` for both the namenode and the datanode.  On the datanode, you should see something like `hive.metastore.uris=thrift://namenode-hostname:9083`.

Comment: @climbage Thanx man. It worked when i stared the thrift service (hive --servce metastore) on namenode. And now i am being able to connect to mysql metasore which is running on master from datanode. But, do you have any idea why it doesn't work when i give username, password and javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL in hive-site.xml?

Comment: Are you by chance running a Cloudera distro or just vanilla Hadoop?

Comment: just simple apache hadoop(vanilla hadoop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this on the Apache wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/adminmanual-metastoreadmin.html#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-RemoteMetastore) it looks like you have to go through the thift service if you have the metastore service running on a remote server.

I would just add the `hive.metastore.uris` property to your hive-site.xml and call it a day.